# Android URLConnection, responce is changing from web to android

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

I am working on an app, where I have to parse the third party website after login in to it. Where `https://customer.onlinelic.in/LICEPS/appmanager/Agent/AgentHome` is home page after login. From here there are some links in the response page where I parse and make a request to each of those links.One of the links take me to a page where I have to enter some inputs and submit the form and it returns me some data based on inputs.

If I do this in web the result is coming fine. But if I request same URL from Android using `HttpUrlConnection` the response coming completely different, infact it is returning above mentioned page, which is home page.

**Here is the web request:**
[image]

If I do the request in android with same request parameters, and valid session id and valid input parameters, response coming differently. Response code is proper but response content is wrong.

**Here is the Android request**
[image]

I checked all headers and parameters, but of no use. Can any one tell me what might be the reason to get different responses.

**EDIT**
Here is my code for request

```
public String initiateRequest(String url, String payload, String referer, String requestType)
    {
        String response = null;
        try
        {
            URL urls = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection urlconn = (HttpsURLConnection) urls.openConnection();
            urlconn.setDoInput(true);
            urlconn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlconn.setRequestMethod(requestType);
            urlconn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            urlconn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            if (!referer.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                urlconn.setRequestProperty("referer", "https://customer.onlinelic.in/LICEPS/appmanager/Agent/AgentHome?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=Agent_policy_tracker_portlet&Agent_policy_tracker_portlet_actionOverride=%2Fportlets%2Fagent%2FAgentPolicyTracker%2Fbegin");
                urlconn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36");
                urlconn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
//                urlconn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
                urlconn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4");
                urlconn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control","max-age=0");

            }
            OutputStream os = urlconn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            response = ServiceNetworkCommunicator.readDataFromInputStream(urlconn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Session is managed by `CookieHandler`

Comment: wheres your code?

Comment: @petey Request code added